# Find if csv has a specific header and if yes, format that specific value

Tags: php, csv

I've been struggling with this PHP problem for a while now. I have a csv file with client info which looks like this.

```
clientName, clientNumber, clientStatus
Name1,123456,1
Name2,123457,0
```

now, the problem is the following. sometimes the csv has a date of birth too...as follows :

```
clientName, clientNumber, clientDOB, clientStatus
Name1,123456,01/10/1980,1
Name2,123457,1980-10-01,0
```

as you can see the dates are in different format. Whilst converting the csv into an array, i need to check if the in the csv there is clientDOB, and if yes, format it to mysql.

```
function dateToMysql($date) {
    $mysqlDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$date)));

    return $mysqlDate;
}

function csvToArray($filename='', $delimiter=',') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();

    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            if(!$header) {
                $header = $row;
            } else {

                if (in_array("clientDOB", $header)) {
                    //echo dateToMysql($header['clientDOB'][$row])."<br>";
                    $data[] = dateToMysql(array_combine($header, $row));
                } else {
                    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(csvToArray($_FILES['csvFile']['name']));
echo "</pre>";
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated function:

```
function csvToArray($filename='', $delimiter=',') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();

    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            $row = array_map('trim', $row);

            if (!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
            {
              $row = array_combine($header, $row);
              if ( isset( $row[ 'clientDOB' ] ) )
                  $row[ 'clientDOB' ] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $row[ 'clientDOB' ] ) );
              $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Notable changes:

- `$row = array_map('trim', $row)` makes sure there's no surrounding spaces around the names and values, otherwise the `['clientDOB']` won't match (because it's `[' clientDOB']`.
- changing the value of `$row['clientDOB']` before appending the `$row` to `$data`. Your `dateToMysql` function expects a `$date` but instead it was passed an associative array.
- using `strtotime` no replacing is needed: it can handle both date formats.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The date though is staying the same as the input (unformatted)


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [clientName] => Alonzo Whitehurst  
            [clientNumber] => 22985047
            [clientDOB] => 10/14/2014
            [clientStatus] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [clientName] => Barbar Orcutt  
            [clientNumber] => 667035098
            [clientDOB] => 2014-12-14
            [clientStatus] => 0
        )

Comment: Nope...been trying some more with your code but it still doesn't work. Looks like that if(isset) isn't doing anything. The array is built but the dates are still not being formatted.

Comment: Yes, the `isset` didn't check the right variable, sorry. Updated (and tested) the answer.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks very much!